# Apache Spark 2.0.0 PySpark manual dataframe creation head scratcher

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe

When I assemble a one row data frame as follows my method successfully brings back the expected data frame.

```
def build_job_finish_data_frame(sql_context, job_load_id, is_success):
    job_complete_record_schema = StructType(
        [
            StructField("job_load_id", IntegerType(), False),
            StructField("terminate_datetime", TimestampType(), False),
            StructField("was_success", BooleanType(), False)
        ]
    )
    data = [
        Row(
            job_load_id=job_load_id,
            terminate_datetime=datetime.now(),
            was_success=is_success
        )
    ]

    return sql_context.createDataFrame(data, job_complete_record_schema)
```

If I change the "terminate_datetime" to "end_datetime" or "finish_datetime" as shown below it throws an error.

```
def build_job_finish_data_frame(sql_context, job_load_id, is_success):
    job_complete_record_schema = StructType(
        [
            StructField("job_load_id", IntegerType(), False),
            StructField("end_datetime", TimestampType(), False),
            StructField("was_success", BooleanType(), False)
        ]
    )
    data = [
        Row(
            job_load_id=job_load_id,
            end_datetime=datetime.now(),
            was_success=is_success
        )
    ]

    return sql_context.createDataFrame(data, job_complete_record_schema)
```

The error I receive is

```
TypeError: IntegerType can not accept object datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 5, 11, 19, 31, 915745) in type <class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

I can change "terminate_datetime" to "start_datetime" and have experimented with other words.

I can see no reason for field name changes breaking this code as it is doing nothing more than building a manual data frame.

This is worrying as I am using data frames to load up a data warehouse where I have no control of the field names.

I am running PySpark on Python 3.3.2 on Fedora 20.

Answer (score 1):

Why the name changes things? The problem is that `Row` is a `tuple` **sorted** by `__fields__`. So the first case creates

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from datetime import datetime

x = Row(job_load_id=1, terminate_datetime=datetime.now(), was_success=True)
x.__fields__
## ['job_load_id', 'terminate_datetime', 'was_success']
```

while the second one creates:

```
y = Row(job_load_id=1, end_datetime=datetime.now(), was_success=True)
y.__fields__
## ['end_datetime', 'job_load_id', 'was_success']
```

This no longer matches the schema you defined which expects `(IntegerType, TimestampType, Boolean)`.

Because `Row` is useful mostly for schema inference and you provide schema directly you can address that by using standard `tuple`:

```
def build_job_finish_data_frame(sql_context, job_load_id, is_success):
    job_complete_record_schema = StructType(
        [
            StructField("job_load_id", IntegerType(), False),
            StructField("end_datetime", TimestampType(), False),
            StructField("was_success", BooleanType(), False)
        ]
    )
    data = [tuple(job_load_id, datetime.now(), is_success)]

    return sql_context.createDataFrame(data, job_complete_record_schema)
```

although creating a single element `DataFrame` looks strange if not pointless.

Comment: Single element `DataFrame`s are useful for testing purposes.